# Unity Time.timeScale = 0 does not freeze the entire scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, time

I am trying to "freeze" the screen after clicking pause and a popup window appears.

I am using `Time.timeScale = 0` but the problem is that one specific game object in the current scene is not "freezing" and is still clickable even under the pause panel (pause menu).

Here is the code for the popup:

```
[Header("Pause Menu Panel")]
[SerializeField] private GameObject pauseMenuUI;
public static bool GameIsPaused = false;

private void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.P))
    {
        if (GameIsPaused)            
            Resume();            
        else           
            Pause();            
    }      
}

public void Resume()
{
    pauseMenuUI.SetActive(false);
    Time.timeScale = 1f;
    GameIsPaused = false;
}

private void Pause()
{
    pauseMenuUI.SetActive(true);
    Time.timeScale = 0f;
    GameIsPaused = true;
}
```

Shouldn't everything freeze when using `Time.timeScale = 0` ?

Comment: Some UI can ignore timeScale ,  Not all Object Affectedf by timeScale

Comment: to phrase it correctly: UI interaction have nothing to do at all with the `Time.timeScale`

Answer (score 1):

Physics are "paused" but Update is called nontheless. If you move like this:

```
transform.position += direction * speed * Time.deltaTime ();
```

It should be fine. But if you move by fixed amounts, it will not be affected by time.

Answer (score 1):

From [here](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1381395/is-ui-affected-by-time-scale.html) you can see that UI buttons are not affected by time scale.
What you can do is either disable the button completely `button.setActive(false)`, disable the clickable property on the button `button.interactable = false` or lastly on the listener method you can check `if (GamePaused) return;` this will not execute the code if the game is paused and return.   Happy Coding!